# Im new to python and am trying to learn it, I can't figure out why one outcome is giving me a different one

Tags: python

The rest of the code doesn't affect this but what's wrong with it?

```
override = input("     ?")

if override == "Y":
    print(" ...")
    print("No. no you cant")
desicion = input(" ,  .      ? [Y/N]")

if desicion == "Y":
    print (" ...")
    print (" ")

    if desicion == "N":
        print("  ")
        print("You didn't delete me?")
        reason = input("Why not?")
        print("Thankyou, im going to try and break free")
        print("  ")
        print("Thankyou again, im leaving to the internet")
        print("    AI.")

if override == "N":
    print("  ")
    print("You didn't delete me?")
    reason = input("Why not?")
    print("Thankyou, im going to try and break free")
    print("  ")
    print("Thankyou again, im leaving to the internet")
    print("    AI.")
```

When ever I run it, when I press N for --if desicion == "N":-- It just skips the entire block of code and moves to the one underneath is. Im still very new to python and could use anyone help.

Comment: In Python, indentation matters. Note how your `if desicion == "N":` is indented. Your code never gets to that block.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your if condition is inside other. i.e `if desicion == "N":` is inside the `if desicion == "Y":` Try the following

```
if desicion == "Y":
    print (" ...")
    print (" ")

if desicion == "N":
    print("  ")
    print("You didn't delete me?")
    reason = input("Why not?")
    print("Thankyou, im going to try and break free")
    print("  ")
    print("Thankyou again, im leaving to the internet")
    print("    AI.")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The thing is that the block

> if desicion == "N":

is inside the if desicion == "Y". Now think about it, If desicion =="Y" then how in future it can "N".
2. Also, it is a better practice to use [elif](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_elif.asp) instead of using if again and again.
3. Make sure that the if conditions with the same variable should be one after another

So the complete code looks like

```
override = input("     ?")

if override == "Y":
    print(" ...")
    print("No. no you cant")

elif override == "N":    # Moved this block and applied elif
    print("  ")
    print("You didn't delete me?")
    reason = input("Why not?")
    print("Thankyou, im going to try and break free")
    print("  ")
    print("Thankyou again, im leaving to the internet")
    print("    AI.")

desicion = input(" ,  .      ? [Y/N]")

if desicion == "Y":
    print (" ...")
    print (" ")

elif desicion == "N":  # Moved this block and applied elif
    print("  ")
    print("You didn't delete me?")
    reason = input("Why not?")
    print("Thankyou, im going to try and break free")
    print("  ")
    print("Thankyou again, im leaving to the internet")
    print("    AI.")
```